# OpenHAB2 access to MODBUS RTU slave device

Tags: modbus, openhab

Running OpenHab2 on my Windows10, I am not able to get OpenHAB2 to request holding register data from the serial port. No MODBUS request are seen on the port.
I installed  NTP-binding (ntp time) (it works), and tried the Modbus binding 1.12.0, seems though only valid for OpenHAB1.

My OpenHAB2 configuration is

.sitemap

```
    sitemap boiler label="My home" 
    {
        Frame label="Date" 
        {
          Text item=Date
          Text item=holding1501 label="Holding1501 out[%.1f °C]"
          Text item=holding1500 label="Holding1500 out[%.1f °C]"
        }
    }
```

.items

```
    DateTime Date  "Date [%1$tA, %1$td.%1$tm.%1$tY %1$tH:%1$tM:%1$tS]"  { channel="ntp:ntp:local:dateTime" }
    Number holding1501 "Holding1501 [%.1f]" <temperature> {channel="modbus:data:localSerial:holding:holding1501:number"}
    Number holding1500 "Holding1500 [%.1f]" <temperature> {channel="modbus:data:localSerial:holding:holding1500:number"}
```

and  .things

```
    Bridge modbus:serial:localSerial [port="COM6", id=10, baud=19200, stopBits="1", parity="even", dataBits=8, encoding="rtu"]
    {
        Bridge poller holding [ start=1500, length=1, refresh=1000, type="holding" ] 
        {
            Thing data holding1500 [ readStart="1500", readValueType="int16", writeStart="1500", writeValueType="int16", writeType="holding" ]
            Thing data holding15011 [ readStart="1501", readValueType="int16", writeStart="1501", writeValueType="int16", writeType="holding" ] 
        }
        Thing data holding1500 [ readStart="1500", readValueType="int16", writeStart="1500", writeValueType="int16", writeType="holding" ]
        Thing data holding15011 [ readStart="1501", readValueType="int16", writeStart="1501", writeValueType="int16", writeType="holding" ] 
    }
```

What am I missing to get MODBUS going in OpenHAB2. References to some tutorials or working examples will be appreciated.

Comment: Ahhh, found a solution myself. 
My attempt to match and OpenHAB2 MODBUS configuration in the .things file was not successful. 
Following the manual/examples here https://www.openhab.org/addons/bindings/modbus1/,  I had a success. Configured the modbus.cfg file, some minor adjustments to the .items file, running a MODBUS RTU slave simulator on COM5 (from www.modbustools.com), OpenHAB now reads holding registers on COM5 (COM5/COM6 is virtual ports via com0com)

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the solution: OpenHAB 2.3.0 is not working for MODBUS v2.x. When using OpenHAB2 2.4.0 (snapshot) MODBUS RTU is working (used com0com to bridge OH2 to MOD_RSsim). Did not manage to get MODBUS/TCP to work, seemed like an IP port connection issue)